# Работа со стоками в php

Tags: php, строки

Есть функция, которая берёт с сайта ржд ссылки на последние новости, но так вышло, что строка, содержащая url отличается от настоящего урла. Вот сама функция со сравнением строк и выводом самих строк:

```
function get_content() {
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press/');
    $old_url_;
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($html->find('a[class=news_list_cardLink]') as $element)
    {
        $old_url_[$i] = $element->href; $i++;
     }
    $new_url = 'http://press.rzd.ru';
    $new_url .= $old_url_[1];
    $real_url = 'http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press? STRUCTURE_ID=654&layer_id=4069&refererPageId=704&refererLayerId=4067&id=81794';
    echo strnatcasecmp($new_url,$real_url);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $new_url;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $real_url;
}
```

А вот так выглядит выхлоп функции:

```
-1
http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press?STRUCTURE_ID=654&layer_id=4069&refererPageId=704&refererLayerId=4067&id=81794
http://press.rzd.ru/news/public/press?STRUCTURE_ID=654&layer_id=4069&refererPageId=704&refererLayerId=4067&id=81794
```

Видно, что строки одинаковые, но они почему-то разные. Так же когда запускаю парсинг по real_url, то сайт отдаёт правильную страницу, а когда по $new_url, то сайт пишет, что произошла ошибка.
Что делать посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что приходит - это когда писали функцию-конвертер, где-то случайно втыкнули русский символ. Пройдитесь строку посимвольно (substr'ом, может и есть функция, но я не помню) посмотрите где и чем отличается.

-1 означает, что у вас первая "меньше" второй.... у вас там \0 или \n не заваляось случайно где-то?

Comment: strcmp вывел -11

Нигде такого нет, всё проверил и не раз

Comment: ХЗ) В доке strcmp говорит, что значение может быть меньше нуля, но не уточняется что это значит. Возмоно порядковый номер символа...

Если у вас совсем-совсем не получается, пришли в комменты строки, только не в чистом виде, возможно сайт их как-то фильтруется, а в base64... Кстати "хеши" у вас должны отличаться.

Comment: Очень удивился, но в base64 они различаются, причём различие идёт после символа &

Comment: Они и должны различаться - функции сравнения строк вам возращают -1 (а если бы были равны - тогда 0).

Хеши можно - там же не секретной информации))?

Comment: модуль числа ничего не значит, это просто остатки имплементации, чтобы не делать лишнюю операцию, важно только >0 <0 ==0

Comment: b8685aef2834c4712a62517755689226 - генерированная ссылка
11bb374b1f5d1885a3f4e83f50328dd7 - скопированная ссылка

Comment: aHR0cDovL3ByZXNzLnJ6ZC5ydS9uZXdzL3B1YmxpYy9wcmVzcz9TVFJVQ1RVUkVfSUQ9NjU0JmFtcDtsYXllcl9pZD00MDY5JmFtcDtyZWZlcmVyUGFnZUlkPTcwNCZhbXA7cmVmZXJlckxheWVySWQ9NDA2NyZhbXA7aWQ9ODE3OTQ=  - сгенерированая
<br>
aHR0cDovL3ByZXNzLnJ6ZC5ydS9uZXdzL3B1YmxpYy9wcmVzcz9TVFJVQ1RVUkVfSUQ9NjU0JmxheWVyX2lkPTQwNjkmcmVmZXJlclBhZ2VJZD03MDQmcmVmZXJlckxheWVySWQ9NDA2NyZpZD04MTc5NA==  - скопированная

Comment: У вас в сгенеренной (первая, более длинная) вместо & используется &amp;. Это правильно, но только для ссылок, которые идут в HTML. А для прямого обращения должно быть просто &.

Возможно у вас где-то вызывается htmlspecialchars... Ну в крайнем случае просто замените 

      $str = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $str);